# MySQL Reader closing immediately

Tags: c#, mysql, reader

I have a method that is recursively populating a list. First it selects the Parent items, then it selects any children it may have using foreign keys. It selects the Parent items fine, but when it starts picking the children, that's when the `Reader` closes for no reason.

I have followed it through in the debugger, and there is no reason that I can see for it to be closing. The search parameters are valid, the search returns items (I checked it manually), and the `Reader` is active. Yet for some reason, as soon as it opens, it closes, without any errors.

- The connection string is valid
- The Reader is valid
- The search parameters are valid
- The command returns results (I tested this one specifically - `WHERE 1 = 1 AND SE.ParentSE = 4;";` has over 10 results)

I don't know what's going on?

```
try
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT 
                                    SE.SEId,
                                    SE.Name,
                                    SE.Status,
                                    SE.Description,
                                    SE.ParentME AS ParentMEId,
                                    SE.ParentSE AS ParentSEId,
                                    SE.Comments AS Comments,
                                    SE.Removed AS Removed,
                                    SE.SupplierId AS SupplierId,
                                    TC.TerminalCount AS TerminalCount,
                                    SE2.Name AS ParentSE,
                                    ME.EquipmentNumber AS ParentME,
                                    D.DSId AS DataSheet,
                                    D.DSType AS DataSheetType,
                                    C.Code AS EquipmentType,
                                    C.Description AS TypeDescription,
                                    C.CodeType AS TypeDiscipline,
                                    SE.EquipmentType AS EquipTypeId,
                                    SE3.SEId AS SE3Id,
                                    SE4.SEId AS SE4Id,
                                    SE5.SEId AS SE5Id,
                                    SE6.SEId AS SE6Id,
                                    SE2.ParentME AS ME2Id,
                                    SE3.ParentME AS ME3Id,
                                    SE4.ParentME AS ME4Id,
                                    SE5.ParentME AS ME5Id,
                                    SE6.ParentME AS ME6Id,
                                    PAC.UDCId AS AreaCodeId,
                                    PAC.Code AS AreaCode,
                                    PAC.Description AS AreaCodeDescription
                                FROM SubEquipment SE
                                LEFT  JOIN DataSheet D ON SE.SEId = D.SEId
                                LEFT JOIN (SELECT SEId, COUNT(*) as TerminalCount FROM Terminal GROUP BY SEId) TC ON SE.SEId = TC.SEId
                                LEFT JOIN SubEquipment SE2 ON SE.ParentSE = SE2.SEId
                                LEFT JOIN MajorEquipment ME ON SE.ParentME = ME.MEId
                                LEFT JOIN UserDefinedCode C ON C.UDCId = SE.EquipmentType
                                LEFT JOIN SubEquipment SE3 ON SE2.ParentSE = SE3.SEId
                                LEFT JOIN SubEquipment SE4 ON SE3.ParentSE = SE4.SEId
                                LEFT JOIN SubEquipment SE5 ON SE4.ParentSE = SE5.SEId
                                LEFT JOIN SubEquipment SE6 ON SE5.ParentSE = SE6.SEId
                                INNER JOIN MajorParentage MP ON SE.SEId = MP.SEId
                                INNER JOIN MajorEquipment MEU ON MP.MEId = MEU.MEId
                                INNER JOIN UserDefinedCode PAC ON MEU.PACId = PAC.UDCId
                                LEFT JOIN ComponentStatus CS1 ON CS1.StatusName = SE.Status
                                WHERE 1 = 1"
                                // " AND SE.ParentSE = @SEParentId"                                    
                                // @SEParentId = 4
                                + parentSearch
                                + ";";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PACId", areaCodeId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaCode", areaCode.Cipher());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ETId", equipmentTypeId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EquipmentType", equipmentType.Cipher());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EquipmentNumber", equipmentNumber.Cipher());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", description.Cipher());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", comments.Cipher());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeDiscipline", typeDiscipline);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEParentId", parentMEId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MEParent", parentMENumber.Cipher());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEParentId", parentSEId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEParent", parentSENumber.Cipher());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEId", excludeSEId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", status.Cipher());

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Read all the results and populate a model with them.
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Do stuff...
                }
                // Finished reading the results
                if (!reader.IsClosed)
                    reader.Close();
            }
        }

        // Finished with the connection
        if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
    }
}
catch (MySqlException e)
{
    ShowMySQLError(e, 4417);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried not including the if-statements to close the Reader the connection?

Comment: I let the using with resources ditch it for me. What he said.

Comment: No change anyway. I just threw that in as a precaution - our team is very precaucious, we've had issues with things not disposing before. I know `using` handles it normally, but let's just say we're paranoid

Comment: Where does recursion factor into this? How many levels? If you need assistance after some time, consider bundling up a reproducible sqlfiddle with create tables with data (sqlfiddle or otherwise) and give the whole thing. Because right now it is a minor fragment of the code perhaps.

Comment: Hold on a second. You are adding values to a query that does not even take parameters. Perhaps you cut and paste `AddWithValue` block by accident from other code, and it is errant, not tripping the try/catch, and it implodes later.

Comment: Sorry @Drew! I accidentally left the parameter in there from my testing. It does use parameters in a few places, I just cut an paste this from my MySQL testing. I'll update it.

Comment: @Drew as for the recursion, this is happening on th first child level. The parents have already been searched (using a diffrent method path), and no it is searching for the first child level. I've double chacked all the other objects, and everything checks out - but that doesn't matter either way, because they don't affect the `Reader`?

Comment: I hang out in the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) room if you want to ping me there anytime with an @ sign .

Comment: Don't forget to upvote, downvote, accept answers if appropriate. It is our feedback, and cheers us on to help the next guy. And if I recall and in the Chat transcripts, I spent at least 30 minutes helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

This method was being used in multiple places throughout the program; but for some reason, it was only *this* call that was closing the `Reader` unexpectedly. On closer inspection - the properties of the reader showed that it had no rows: `HasRows = false`. Meaning that there was something wrong with the query.

I looked again, and found that the issue was an overlooked parameter (which I trimmed for the sake of the question - I didn't think it was necessary). There were a few default `boolean` parameters, one was set to true, causing the query to return an empty result.

Moral of the story: *Understand what your code is doing!*